# Cleaning and merging csv files python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, data-analysis

So I have been trawling the net for a while now trying to find the best way to clean and merge a set of .csv files ready to work on. I have managed to get some code that kind of does what I want, but not that its complete, it basically does nothing when run. This is what I have so far for cleaning:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    #pick out empty spaces in the csv file
    missing_values = ["--", " ", "0","-"]
    dff = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_august_2014.csv", na_values = missing_values)

    print(dff['Percentage of Homicide Convictions'])
    print(dff['Percentage of Homicide Convictions'].isnull())

    #detecting numbers
    cnt=0
    for row in dff['Percentage of Homicide Convictions']:
        try:
            int(row)
            dff.loc[cnt, 'Percentage of Homicide Convictions'] = np.nan
        except ValueError:
            pass
        cnt = cnt + 1

    #replace empty values with 0
    dff['Percentage of Homicide Convictions'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

    #drop row with nan
    dff = dff.dropna()


    print(dff)
```

output of code:

```
RESTART: C:\Users\Kinkerman\Downloads\Uni\Data Analytics\Dataset_Assignment\2014\Combine    mod.py
```

There is also an issue with my merge code, it just returns nothing. And I am unsure about how to label them so as to differentiate them when merged. This is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    path = "C:/Users/Kinkerman/Downloads/Uni/Data     Analytics/Dataset_Assignment/2014"

    part1 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_april_2014.csv")
    part2 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_august_2014.csv")
    part3 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_december_2014.csv")
    part4 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_february_2014.csv")
    part5 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_january_2014.csv")
    part6 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_july_2014.csv")
    part7 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_june_2014.csv")
    part8 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_march_2014.csv")
    part9 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_may_2014.csv")
    part10 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_november_2014.csv")
    part11 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_october_2014.csv")
    part12 = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_september_2014.csv")

    combined_csv = pd.concat([part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9, part10, part11, part12])

    combined_csv.drop(["Unnamed: 0"], inplace=True, axis=1)

    combined_csv.to_csv("principal_offence_year_2014")
```

output of code:

Nothing

```
        Number of Homicide Convictions  Percentage of Homicide Convictions  Number of Homicide Unsuccessful Percentage of Homicide Unsuccessful Number of Offences Against The Person Convictions   Percentage of Offences Against The Person Convictions   Number of Offences Against The Person Unsuccessful  Percentage of Offences Against The Person Unsuccessful  Number of Sexual Offences Convictions   Percentage of Sexual Offences Convictions   Number of Sexual Offences Unsuccessful  Percentage of Sexual Offences Unsuccessful  Number of Burglary Convictions  Percentage of Burglary Convictions  Number of Burglary Unsuccessful Percentage of Burglary Unsuccessful Number of Robbery Convictions   Percentage of Robbery Convictions   Number of Robbery Unsuccessful  Percentage of Robbery Unsuccessful  Number of Theft And Handling Convictions    Percentage of Theft And Handling Convictions    Number of Theft And Handling Unsuccessful   Percentage of Theft And Handling Unsuccessful   Number of Fraud And Forgery Convictions Percentage of Fraud And Forgery Convictions Number of Fraud And Forgery Unsuccessful    Percentage of Fraud And Forgery Unsuccessful    Number of Criminal Damage Convictions   Percentage of Criminal Damage Convictions   Number of Criminal Damage Unsuccessful  Percentage of Criminal Damage Unsuccessful  Number of Drugs Offences Convictions    Percentage of Drugs Offences Convictions    Number of Drugs Offences Unsuccessful   Percentage of Drugs Offences Unsuccessful   Number of Public Order Offences Convictions Percentage of Public Order Offences Convictions Number of Public Order Offences Unsuccessful    Percentage of Public Order Offences Unsuccessful    Number of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Convictions   Percentage of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Convictions   Number of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Unsuccessful  Percentage of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Unsuccessful  Number of Motoring Offences Convictions Percentage of Motoring Offences Convictions Number of Motoring Offences Unsuccessful    Percentage of Motoring Offences Unsuccessful    Number of Admin Finalised Unsuccessful  Percentage of L Motoring Offences Unsuccessful
National    81  85.30%  14  14.70%  7,805   74.10%  2,722   25.90%  698 72.20%  269 27.80%  1,470   86.70%  226 13.30%  517 81.70%  116 18.30%  10,045  92.30%  840 7.70%   666 86.00%  108 14.00%  2,259   85.20%  391 14.80%  4,536   94.20%  279 5.80%   3,549   84.40%  654 15.60%  2,640   83.70%  513 16.30%  8,283   86.30%  1,314   13.70%  718 100.00%
Avon and Somerset   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   167 78.80%  45  21.20%  36  81.80%  8   18.20%  37  94.90%  2   5.10%   9   75.00%  3   25.00%  266 92.70%  21  7.30%   11  100.00% 0   0.00%   54  90.00%  6   10.00%  135 98.50%  2   1.50%   68  86.10%  11  13.90%  66  80.50%  16  19.50%  188 83.60%  37  16.40%  24  100.00%
Bedfordshire    0   -   0   -   69  75.00%  23  25.00%  5   83.30%  1   16.70%  16  94.10%  1   5.90%   4   100.00% 0   0.00%   98  91.60%  9   8.40%   8   80.00%  2   20.00%  20  76.90%  6   23.10%  45  95.70%  2   4.30%   29  82.90%  6   17.10%  11  64.70%  6   35.30%  40  88.90%  5   11.10%  16  100.00%
Cambridgeshire  0   -   0   -   99  81.10%  23  18.90%  6   66.70%  3   33.30%  8   100.00% 0   0.00%   6   85.70%  1   14.30%  107 91.50%  10  8.50%   7   100.00% 0   0.00%   21  95.50%  1   4.50%   40  95.20%  2   4.80%   45  83.30%  9   16.70%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  79  92.90%  6   7.10%   4   100.00%
Cheshire    1   50.00%  1   50.00%  140 74.90%  47  25.10%  17  85.00%  3   15.00%  26  89.70%  3   10.30%  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   206 98.10%  4   1.90%   16  88.90%  2   11.10%  35  79.50%  9   20.50%  75  88.20%  10  11.80%  86  92.50%  7   7.50%   50  89.30%  6   10.70%  209 94.60%  12  5.40%   1   100.00%
Cleveland   0   -   0   -   85  67.50%  41  32.50%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  25  71.40%  10  28.60%  5   71.40%  2   28.60%  254 88.80%  32  11.20%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  32  80.00%  8   20.00%  63  90.00%  7   10.00%  74  73.30%  27  26.70%  28  84.80%  5   15.20%  124 87.90%  17  12.10%  10  100.00%
Cumbria 0   -   0   -   77  80.20%  19  19.80%  8   88.90%  1   11.10%  12  92.30%  1   7.70%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   108 94.70%  6   5.30%   5   100.00% 0   0.00%   37  94.90%  2   5.10%   42  95.50%  2   4.50%   40  95.20%  2   4.80%   64  98.50%  1   1.50%   95  90.50%  10  9.50%   12  100.00%
Derbyshire  0   -   0   -   151 72.60%  57  27.40%  8   57.10%  6   42.90%  31  91.20%  3   8.80%   8   72.70%  3   27.30%  203 93.10%  15  6.90%   11  55.00%  9   45.00%  40  85.10%  7   14.90%  75  89.30%  9   10.70%  50  92.60%  4   7.40%   46  75.40%  15  24.60%  258 95.20%  13  4.80%   16  100.00%
Devon and Cornwall  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   157 75.80%  50  24.20%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  16  94.10%  1   5.90%   6   100.00% 0   0.00%   151 93.80%  10  6.20%   8   100.00% 0   0.00%   56  90.30%  6   9.70%   70  92.10%  6   7.90%   65  76.50%  20  23.50%  64  82.10%  14  17.90%  189 91.70%  17  8.30%   15  100.00%
Dorset  0   -   0   -   73  82.00%  16  18.00%  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   18  94.70%  1   5.30%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   123 91.80%  11  8.20%   7   77.80%  2   22.20%  24  85.70%  4   14.30%  29  93.50%  2   6.50%   45  93.80%  3   6.30%   25  96.20%  1   3.80%   71  91.00%  7   9.00%   5   100.00%
Durham  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   75  74.30%  26  25.70%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  30  100.00% 0   0.00%   0   0.00%   1   100.00% 144 88.30%  19  11.70%  4   44.40%  5   55.60%  43  86.00%  7   14.00%  19  90.50%  2   9.50%   58  81.70%  13  18.30%  12  80.00%  3   20.00%  66  95.70%  3   4.30%   0   -
Dyfed Powys 0   -   0   -   63  70.80%  26  29.20%  0   0.00%   1   100.00% 17  85.00%  3   15.00%  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   56  91.80%  5   8.20%   2   66.70%  1   33.30%  27  87.10%  4   12.90%  76  93.80%  5   6.20%   28  71.80%  11  28.20%  20  100.00% 0   0.00%   178 92.20%  15  7.80%   5   100.00%
Essex   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   261 79.30%  68  20.70%  20  74.10%  7   25.90%  39  76.50%  12  23.50%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  280 96.60%  10  3.40%   16  80.00%  4   20.00%  63  80.80%  15  19.20%  97  99.00%  1   1.00%   79  96.30%  3   3.70%   52  82.50%  11  17.50%  175 89.30%  21  10.70%  20  100.00%
Gloucestershire 0   -   0   -   41  75.90%  13  24.10%  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  13  100.00% 0   0.00%   0   0.00%   1   100.00% 68  89.50%  8   10.50%  9   81.80%  2   18.20%  14  93.30%  1   6.70%   22  88.00%  3   12.00%  14  87.50%  2   12.50%  19  76.00%  6   24.00%  80  94.10%  5   5.90%   11  100.00%
GreaterManchester   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   471 82.10%  103 17.90%  44  73.30%  16  26.70%  87  85.30%  15  14.70%  29  78.40%  8   21.60%  532 96.00%  22  4.00%   51  87.90%  7   12.10%  172 90.10%  19  9.90%   239 94.10%  15  5.90%   249 92.60%  20  7.40%   132 91.00%  13  9.00%   455 87.00%  68  13.00%  47  100.00%
Gwent   0   -   0   -   77  74.80%  26  25.20%  6   50.00%  6   50.00%  20  80.00%  5   20.00%  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   124 94.70%  7   5.30%   8   100.00% 0   0.00%   20  71.40%  8   28.60%  55  94.80%  3   5.20%   58  81.70%  13  18.30%  16  80.00%  4   20.00%  66  76.70%  20  23.30%  4   100.00%
Hampshire   2   100.00% 0   0.00%   253 74.20%  88  25.80%  18  64.30%  10  35.70%  38  82.60%  8   17.40%  8   61.50%  5   38.50%  317 92.40%  26  7.60%   19  76.00%  6   24.00%  79  86.80%  12  13.20%  134 91.20%  13  8.80%   95  84.10%  18  15.90%  104 83.20%  21  16.80%  227 90.40%  24  9.60%   22  100.00%
Hertfordshire   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   132 77.20%  39  22.80%  15  83.30%  3   16.70%  29  87.90%  4   12.10%  12  100.00% 0   0.00%   210 89.40%  25  10.60%  23  82.10%  5   17.90%  47  94.00%  3   6.00%   114 93.40%  8   6.60%   83  91.20%  8   8.80%   12  85.70%  2   14.30%  158 86.80%  24  13.20%  22  100.00%
Humberside  0   -   0   -   181 88.30%  24  11.70%  12  60.00%  8   40.00%  41  85.40%  7   14.60%  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   229 94.20%  14  5.80%   14  93.30%  1   6.70%   44  93.60%  3   6.40%   55  94.80%  3   5.20%   96  88.90%  12  11.10%  22  81.50%  5   18.50%  119 83.20%  24  16.80%  13  100.00%
Kent    9   64.30%  5   35.70%  235 76.10%  74  23.90%  17  60.70%  11  39.30%  44  97.80%  1   2.20%   9   75.00%  3   25.00%  305 90.20%  33  9.80%   11  78.60%  3   21.40%  65  74.70%  22  25.30%  109 96.50%  4   3.50%   36  72.00%  14  28.00%  125 81.70%  28  18.30%  164 91.10%  16  8.90%   17  100.00%
Lancashire  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   265 70.30%  112 29.70%  30  69.80%  13  30.20%  63  85.10%  11  14.90%  9   81.80%  2   18.20%  272 94.80%  15  5.20%   19  82.60%  4   17.40%  93  83.80%  18  16.20%  114 92.70%  9   7.30%   147 90.70%  15  9.30%   113 89.70%  13  10.30%  256 84.50%  47  15.50%  17  100.00%
Leicestershire  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  140 78.70%  38  21.30%  6   54.50%  5   45.50%  26  81.30%  6   18.80%  4   50.00%  4   50.00%  166 94.30%  10  5.70%   10  90.90%  1   9.10%   38  84.40%  7   15.60%  36  97.30%  1   2.70%   53  85.50%  9   14.50%  17  77.30%  5   22.70%  193 92.80%  15  7.20%   4   100.00%
Lincolnshire    0   -   0   -   89  83.20%  18  16.80%  10  90.90%  1   9.10%   20  90.90%  2   9.10%   2   100.00% 0   0.00%   138 92.60%  11  7.40%   5   83.30%  1   16.70%  17  100.00% 0   0.00%   26  92.90%  2   7.10%   44  84.60%  8   15.40%  23  82.10%  5   17.90%  125 89.90%  14  10.10%  11  100.00%
Merseyside  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   228 79.20%  60  20.80%  17  89.50%  2   10.50%  33  82.50%  7   17.50%  8   61.50%  5   38.50%  298 92.30%  25  7.70%   12  92.30%  1   7.70%   56  86.20%  9   13.80%  285 96.90%  9   3.10%   101 75.90%  32  24.10%  106 88.30%  14  11.70%  222 89.50%  26  10.50%  21  100.00%
Metropolitan and City   21  91.30%  2   8.70%   1,129   67.40%  546 32.60%  117 65.70%  61  34.30%  224 84.20%  42  15.80%  179 85.60%  30  14.40%  1,273   91.00%  126 9.00%   179 87.70%  25  12.30%  271 82.90%  56  17.10%  1,098   93.90%  71  6.10%   639 81.50%  145 18.50%  482 86.40%  76  13.60%  1,404   77.60%  406 22.40%  180 100.00%
Norfolk 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   165 79.30%  43  20.70%  8   80.00%  2   20.00%  12  85.70%  2   14.30%  3   100.00% 0   0.00%   146 91.30%  14  8.80%   11  91.70%  1   8.30%   52  91.20%  5   8.80%   76  96.20%  3   3.80%   58  86.60%  9   13.40%  49  90.70%  5   9.30%   107 87.70%  15  12.30%  9   100.00%
Northamptonshire    2   100.00% 0   0.00%   69  65.70%  36  34.30%  13  68.40%  6   31.60%  23  92.00%  2   8.00%   11  91.70%  1   8.30%   135 86.00%  22  14.00%  7   87.50%  1   12.50%  21  91.30%  2   8.70%   31  93.90%  2   6.10%   44  83.00%  9   17.00%  11  78.60%  3   21.40%  97  89.00%  12  11.00%  8   100.00%
Northumbria 3   100.00% 0   0.00%   225 68.40%  104 31.60%  10  47.60%  11  52.40%  54  87.10%  8   12.90%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  415 84.90%  74  15.10%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  99  81.10%  23  18.90%  98  83.80%  19  16.20%  109 76.20%  34  23.80%  188 77.00%  56  23.00%  249 86.80%  38  13.20%  11  100.00%
North Wales 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   100 76.30%  31  23.70%  7   53.80%  6   46.20%  21  95.50%  1   4.50%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   137 93.20%  10  6.80%   9   90.00%  1   10.00%  45  86.50%  7   13.50%  40  95.20%  2   4.80%   43  95.60%  2   4.40%   68  87.20%  10  12.80%  150 88.80%  19  11.20%  2   100.00%
North Yorkshire 1   50.00%  1   50.00%  92  86.80%  14  13.20%  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   6   75.00%  2   25.00%  6   85.70%  1   14.30%  137 90.70%  14  9.30%   6   85.70%  1   14.30%  19  67.90%  9   32.10%  38  95.00%  2   5.00%   42  87.50%  6   12.50%  11  55.00%  9   45.00%  78  90.70%  8   9.30%   14  100.00%
Nottinghamshire 2   100.00% 0   0.00%   182 71.90%  71  28.10%  12  80.00%  3   20.00%  30  100.00% 0   0.00%   11  57.90%  8   42.10%  241 96.00%  10  4.00%   10  100.00% 0   0.00%   45  86.50%  7   13.50%  100 96.20%  4   3.80%   46  82.10%  10  17.90%  51  78.50%  14  21.50%  154 92.80%  12  7.20%   2   100.00%
South Wales 0   -   0   -   232 72.50%  88  27.50%  13  65.00%  7   35.00%  55  94.80%  3   5.20%   10  100.00% 0   0.00%   289 94.40%  17  5.60%   9   90.00%  1   10.00%  64  97.00%  2   3.00%   112 100.00% 0   0.00%   150 93.20%  11  6.80%   47  87.00%  7   13.00%  323 81.20%  75  18.80%  11  100.00%
South Yorkshire 2   100.00% 0   0.00%   218 80.40%  53  19.60%  18  90.00%  2   10.00%  44  95.70%  2   4.30%   9   64.30%  5   35.70%  350 95.90%  15  4.10%   9   81.80%  2   18.20%  75  91.50%  7   8.50%   114 95.00%  6   5.00%   78  84.80%  14  15.20%  41  85.40%  7   14.60%  162 89.50%  19  10.50%  13  100.00%
Staffordshire   0   -   0   -   150 69.40%  66  30.60%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  20  95.20%  1   4.80%   8   80.00%  2   20.00%  161 85.60%  27  14.40%  11  91.70%  1   8.30%   55  74.30%  19  25.70%  80  93.00%  6   7.00%   85  81.70%  19  18.30%  63  90.00%  7   10.00%  147 83.10%  30  16.90%  8   100.00%
Suffolk 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   138 87.30%  20  12.70%  7   100.00% 0   0.00%   14  73.70%  5   26.30%  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  111 95.70%  5   4.30%   5   83.30%  1   16.70%  28  90.30%  3   9.70%   40  97.60%  1   2.40%   61  91.00%  6   9.00%   43  86.00%  7   14.00%  68  88.30%  9   11.70%  5   100.00%
Surrey  0   -   0   -   93  75.60%  30  24.40%  11  61.10%  7   38.90%  5   62.50%  3   37.50%  8   88.90%  1   11.10%  111 88.80%  14  11.20%  17  94.40%  1   5.60%   23  82.10%  5   17.90%  55  96.50%  2   3.50%   39  83.00%  8   17.00%  37  71.20%  15  28.80%  134 87.60%  19  12.40%  17  100.00%
Sussex  0   -   0   -   171 80.30%  42  19.70%  15  65.20%  8   34.80%  35  87.50%  5   12.50%  7   100.00% 0   0.00%   190 91.80%  17  8.20%   14  73.70%  5   26.30%  36  85.70%  6   14.30%  80  95.20%  4   4.80%   72  84.70%  13  15.30%  74  72.50%  28  27.50%  161 89.40%  19  10.60%  17  100.00%
Thames Valley   9   100.00% 0   0.00%   214 65.20%  114 34.80%  26  72.20%  10  27.80%  40  87.00%  6   13.00%  10  62.50%  6   37.50%  296 92.50%  24  7.50%   15  83.30%  3   16.70%  51  82.30%  11  17.70%  122 93.10%  9   6.90%   105 84.00%  20  16.00%  32  76.20%  10  23.80%  280 89.70%  32  10.30%  40  100.00%
Warwickshire    0   -   0   -   35  76.10%  11  23.90%  7   87.50%  1   12.50%  10  100.00% 0   0.00%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   76  96.20%  3   3.80%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   10  83.30%  2   16.70%  18  94.70%  1   5.30%   15  78.90%  4   21.10%  32  91.40%  3   8.60%   154 90.60%  16  9.40%   0   -
West Mercia 1   50.00%  1   50.00%  156 78.80%  42  21.20%  24  85.70%  4   14.30%  14  82.40%  3   17.60%  5   83.30%  1   16.70%  169 93.40%  12  6.60%   5   100.00% 0   0.00%   47  92.20%  4   7.80%   55  98.20%  1   1.80%   66  86.80%  10  13.20%  49  89.10%  6   10.90%  198 88.80%  25  11.20%  3   100.00%
West Midlands   6   66.70%  3   33.30%  413 64.90%  223 35.10%  28  75.70%  9   24.30%  90  82.60%  19  17.40%  55  77.50%  16  22.50%  558 92.20%  47  7.80%   35  97.20%  1   2.80%   109 83.20%  22  16.80%  226 92.60%  18  7.40%   116 77.90%  33  22.10%  164 79.60%  42  20.40%  304 86.10%  49  13.90%  16  100.00%
West Yorkshire  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   420 76.60%  128 23.40%  40  83.30%  8   16.70%  78  80.40%  19  19.60%  30  93.80%  2   6.30%   505 93.70%  34  6.30%   22  88.00%  3   12.00%  86  81.90%  19  18.10%  173 95.60%  8   4.40%   116 80.00%  29  20.00%  52  83.90%  10  16.10%  297 85.10%  52  14.90%  35  100.00%
Wiltshire   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   74  75.50%  24  24.50%  9   69.20%  4   30.80%  6   100.00% 0   0.00%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   90  92.80%  7   7.20%   4   80.00%  1   20.00%  26  83.90%  5   16.10%  25  100.00% 0   0.00%   22  81.50%  5   18.50%  13  86.70%  2   13.30%  79  85.90%  13  14.10%  10  100.00%
    Number of Homicide Convictions  Percentage of Homicide Convictions  Number of Homicide Unsuccessful Percentage of Homicide Unsuccessful Number of Offences Against The Person Convictions   Percentage of Offences Against The Person Convictions   Number of Offences Against The Person Unsuccessful  Percentage of Offences Against The Person Unsuccessful  Number of Sexual Offences Convictions   Percentage of Sexual Offences Convictions   Number of Sexual Offences Unsuccessful  Percentage of Sexual Offences Unsuccessful  Number of Burglary Convictions  Percentage of Burglary Convictions  Number of Burglary Unsuccessful Percentage of Burglary Unsuccessful Number of Robbery Convictions   Percentage of Robbery Convictions   Number of Robbery Unsuccessful  Percentage of Robbery Unsuccessful  Number of Theft And Handling Convictions    Percentage of Theft And Handling Convictions    Number of Theft And Handling Unsuccessful   Percentage of Theft And Handling Unsuccessful   Number of Fraud And Forgery Convictions Percentage of Fraud And Forgery Convictions Number of Fraud And Forgery Unsuccessful    Percentage of Fraud And Forgery Unsuccessful    Number of Criminal Damage Convictions   Percentage of Criminal Damage Convictions   Number of Criminal Damage Unsuccessful  Percentage of Criminal Damage Unsuccessful  Number of Drugs Offences Convictions    Percentage of Drugs Offences Convictions    Number of Drugs Offences Unsuccessful   Percentage of Drugs Offences Unsuccessful   Number of Public Order Offences Convictions Percentage of Public Order Offences Convictions Number of Public Order Offences Unsuccessful    Percentage of Public Order Offences Unsuccessful    Number of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Convictions   Percentage of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Convictions   Number of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Unsuccessful  Percentage of All Other Offences (excluding Motoring) Unsuccessful  Number of Motoring Offences Convictions Percentage of Motoring Offences Convictions Number of Motoring Offences Unsuccessful    Percentage of Motoring Offences Unsuccessful    Number of Admin Finalised Unsuccessful  Percentage of L Motoring Offences Unsuccessful
National    81  85.30%  14  14.70%  7,805   74.10%  2,722   25.90%  698 72.20%  269 27.80%  1,470   86.70%  226 13.30%  517 81.70%  116 18.30%  10,045  92.30%  840 7.70%   666 86.00%  108 14.00%  2,259   85.20%  391 14.80%  4,536   94.20%  279 5.80%   3,549   84.40%  654 15.60%  2,640   83.70%  513 16.30%  8,283   86.30%  1,314   13.70%  718 100.00%
Avon and Somerset   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   167 78.80%  45  21.20%  36  81.80%  8   18.20%  37  94.90%  2   5.10%   9   75.00%  3   25.00%  266 92.70%  21  7.30%   11  100.00% 0   0.00%   54  90.00%  6   10.00%  135 98.50%  2   1.50%   68  86.10%  11  13.90%  66  80.50%  16  19.50%  188 83.60%  37  16.40%  24  100.00%
Bedfordshire    0   -   0   -   69  75.00%  23  25.00%  5   83.30%  1   16.70%  16  94.10%  1   5.90%   4   100.00% 0   0.00%   98  91.60%  9   8.40%   8   80.00%  2   20.00%  20  76.90%  6   23.10%  45  95.70%  2   4.30%   29  82.90%  6   17.10%  11  64.70%  6   35.30%  40  88.90%  5   11.10%  16  100.00%
Cambridgeshire  0   -   0   -   99  81.10%  23  18.90%  6   66.70%  3   33.30%  8   100.00% 0   0.00%   6   85.70%  1   14.30%  107 91.50%  10  8.50%   7   100.00% 0   0.00%   21  95.50%  1   4.50%   40  95.20%  2   4.80%   45  83.30%  9   16.70%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  79  92.90%  6   7.10%   4   100.00%
Cheshire    1   50.00%  1   50.00%  140 74.90%  47  25.10%  17  85.00%  3   15.00%  26  89.70%  3   10.30%  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   206 98.10%  4   1.90%   16  88.90%  2   11.10%  35  79.50%  9   20.50%  75  88.20%  10  11.80%  86  92.50%  7   7.50%   50  89.30%  6   10.70%  209 94.60%  12  5.40%   1   100.00%
Cleveland   0   -   0   -   85  67.50%  41  32.50%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  25  71.40%  10  28.60%  5   71.40%  2   28.60%  254 88.80%  32  11.20%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  32  80.00%  8   20.00%  63  90.00%  7   10.00%  74  73.30%  27  26.70%  28  84.80%  5   15.20%  124 87.90%  17  12.10%  10  100.00%
Cumbria 0   -   0   -   77  80.20%  19  19.80%  8   88.90%  1   11.10%  12  92.30%  1   7.70%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   108 94.70%  6   5.30%   5   100.00% 0   0.00%   37  94.90%  2   5.10%   42  95.50%  2   4.50%   40  95.20%  2   4.80%   64  98.50%  1   1.50%   95  90.50%  10  9.50%   12  100.00%
Derbyshire  0   -   0   -   151 72.60%  57  27.40%  8   57.10%  6   42.90%  31  91.20%  3   8.80%   8   72.70%  3   27.30%  203 93.10%  15  6.90%   11  55.00%  9   45.00%  40  85.10%  7   14.90%  75  89.30%  9   10.70%  50  92.60%  4   7.40%   46  75.40%  15  24.60%  258 95.20%  13  4.80%   16  100.00%
Devon and Cornwall  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   157 75.80%  50  24.20%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  16  94.10%  1   5.90%   6   100.00% 0   0.00%   151 93.80%  10  6.20%   8   100.00% 0   0.00%   56  90.30%  6   9.70%   70  92.10%  6   7.90%   65  76.50%  20  23.50%  64  82.10%  14  17.90%  189 91.70%  17  8.30%   15  100.00%
Dorset  0   -   0   -   73  82.00%  16  18.00%  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   18  94.70%  1   5.30%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   123 91.80%  11  8.20%   7   77.80%  2   22.20%  24  85.70%  4   14.30%  29  93.50%  2   6.50%   45  93.80%  3   6.30%   25  96.20%  1   3.80%   71  91.00%  7   9.00%   5   100.00%
Durham  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   75  74.30%  26  25.70%  11  73.30%  4   26.70%  30  100.00% 0   0.00%   0   0.00%   1   100.00% 144 88.30%  19  11.70%  4   44.40%  5   55.60%  43  86.00%  7   14.00%  19  90.50%  2   9.50%   58  81.70%  13  18.30%  12  80.00%  3   20.00%  66  95.70%  3   4.30%   0   -
Dyfed Powys 0   -   0   -   63  70.80%  26  29.20%  0   0.00%   1   100.00% 17  85.00%  3   15.00%  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   56  91.80%  5   8.20%   2   66.70%  1   33.30%  27  87.10%  4   12.90%  76  93.80%  5   6.20%   28  71.80%  11  28.20%  20  100.00% 0   0.00%   178 92.20%  15  7.80%   5   100.00%
Essex   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   261 79.30%  68  20.70%  20  74.10%  7   25.90%  39  76.50%  12  23.50%  6   75.00%  2   25.00%  280 96.60%  10  3.40%   16  80.00%  4   20.00%  63  80.80%  15  19.20%  97  99.00%  1   1.00%   79  96.30%  3   3.70%   52  82.50%  11  17.50%  175 89.30%  21  10.70%  20  100.00%
Gloucestershire 0   -   0   -   41  75.90%  13  24.10%  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  13  100.00% 0   0.00%   0   0.00%   1   100.00% 68  89.50%  8   10.50%  9   81.80%  2   18.20%  14  93.30%  1   6.70%   22  88.00%  3   12.00%  14  87.50%  2   12.50%  19  76.00%  6   24.00%  80  94.10%  5   5.90%   11  100.00%
GreaterManchester   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   471 82.10%  103 17.90%  44  73.30%  16  26.70%  87  85.30%  15  14.70%  29  78.40%  8   21.60%  532 96.00%  22  4.00%   51  87.90%  7   12.10%  172 90.10%  19  9.90%   239 94.10%  15  5.90%   249 92.60%  20  7.40%   132 91.00%  13  9.00%   455 87.00%  68  13.00%  47  100.00%
Gwent   0   -   0   -   77  74.80%  26  25.20%  6   50.00%  6   50.00%  20  80.00%  5   20.00%  2   100.00% 0   0.00%   124 94.70%  7   5.30%   8   100.00% 0   0.00%   20  71.40%  8   28.60%  55  94.80%  3   5.20%   58  81.70%  13  18.30%  16  80.00%  4   20.00%  66  76.70%  20  23.30%  4   100.00%
Hampshire   2   100.00% 0   0.00%   253 74.20%  88  25.80%  18  64.30%  10  35.70%  38  82.60%  8   17.40%  8   61.50%  5   38.50%  317 92.40%  26  7.60%   19  76.00%  6   24.00%  79  86.80%  12  13.20%  134 91.20%  13  8.80%   95  84.10%  18  15.90%  104 83.20%  21  16.80%  227 90.40%  24  9.60%   22  100.00%
Hertfordshire   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   132 77.20%  39  22.80%  15  83.30%  3   16.70%  29  87.90%  4   12.10%  12  100.00% 0   0.00%   210 89.40%  25  10.60%  23  82.10%  5   17.90%  47  94.00%  3   6.00%   114 93.40%  8   6.60%   83  91.20%  8   8.80%   12  85.70%  2   14.30%  158 86.80%  24  13.20%  22  100.00%
Humberside  0   -   0   -   181 88.30%  24  11.70%  12  60.00%  8   40.00%  41  85.40%  7   14.60%  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   229 94.20%  14  5.80%   14  93.30%  1   6.70%   44  93.60%  3   6.40%   55  94.80%  3   5.20%   96  88.90%  12  11.10%  22  81.50%  5   18.50%  119 83.20%  24  16.80%  13  100.00%
Kent    9   64.30%  5   35.70%  235 76.10%  74  23.90%  17  60.70%  11  39.30%  44  97.80%  1   2.20%   9   75.00%  3   25.00%  305 90.20%  33  9.80%   11  78.60%  3   21.40%  65  74.70%  22  25.30%  109 96.50%  4   3.50%   36  72.00%  14  28.00%  125 81.70%  28  18.30%  164 91.10%  16  8.90%   17  100.00%
Lancashire  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   265 70.30%  112 29.70%  30  69.80%  13  30.20%  63  85.10%  11  14.90%  9   81.80%  2   18.20%  272 94.80%  15  5.20%   19  82.60%  4   17.40%  93  83.80%  18  16.20%  114 92.70%  9   7.30%   147 90.70%  15  9.30%   113 89.70%  13  10.30%  256 84.50%  47  15.50%  17  100.00%
Leicestershire  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  140 78.70%  38  21.30%  6   54.50%  5   45.50%  26  81.30%  6   18.80%  4   50.00%  4   50.00%  166 94.30%  10  5.70%   10  90.90%  1   9.10%   38  84.40%  7   15.60%  36  97.30%  1   2.70%   53  85.50%  9   14.50%  17  77.30%  5   22.70%  193 92.80%  15  7.20%   4   100.00%
Lincolnshire    0   -   0   -   89  83.20%  18  16.80%  10  90.90%  1   9.10%   20  90.90%  2   9.10%   2   100.00% 0   0.00%   138 92.60%  11  7.40%   5   83.30%  1   16.70%  17  100.00% 0   0.00%   26  92.90%  2   7.10%   44  84.60%  8   15.40%  23  82.10%  5   17.90%  125 89.90%  14  10.10%  11  100.00%
Merseyside  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   228 79.20%  60  20.80%  17  89.50%  2   10.50%  33  82.50%  7   17.50%  8   61.50%  5   38.50%  298 92.30%  25  7.70%   12  92.30%  1   7.70%   56  86.20%  9   13.80%  285 96.90%  9   3.10%   101 75.90%  32  24.10%  106 88.30%  14  11.70%  222 89.50%  26  10.50%  21  100.00%
Metropolitan and City   21  91.30%  2   8.70%   1,129   67.40%  546 32.60%  117 65.70%  61  34.30%  224 84.20%  42  15.80%  179 85.60%  30  14.40%  1,273   91.00%  126 9.00%   179 87.70%  25  12.30%  271 82.90%  56  17.10%  1,098   93.90%  71  6.10%   639 81.50%  145 18.50%  482 86.40%  76  13.60%  1,404   77.60%  406 22.40%  180 100.00%
Norfolk 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   165 79.30%  43  20.70%  8   80.00%  2   20.00%  12  85.70%  2   14.30%  3   100.00% 0   0.00%   146 91.30%  14  8.80%   11  91.70%  1   8.30%   52  91.20%  5   8.80%   76  96.20%  3   3.80%   58  86.60%  9   13.40%  49  90.70%  5   9.30%   107 87.70%  15  12.30%  9   100.00%
Northamptonshire    2   100.00% 0   0.00%   69  65.70%  36  34.30%  13  68.40%  6   31.60%  23  92.00%  2   8.00%   11  91.70%  1   8.30%   135 86.00%  22  14.00%  7   87.50%  1   12.50%  21  91.30%  2   8.70%   31  93.90%  2   6.10%   44  83.00%  9   17.00%  11  78.60%  3   21.40%  97  89.00%  12  11.00%  8   100.00%
Northumbria 3   100.00% 0   0.00%   225 68.40%  104 31.60%  10  47.60%  11  52.40%  54  87.10%  8   12.90%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  415 84.90%  74  15.10%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  99  81.10%  23  18.90%  98  83.80%  19  16.20%  109 76.20%  34  23.80%  188 77.00%  56  23.00%  249 86.80%  38  13.20%  11  100.00%
North Wales 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   100 76.30%  31  23.70%  7   53.80%  6   46.20%  21  95.50%  1   4.50%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   137 93.20%  10  6.80%   9   90.00%  1   10.00%  45  86.50%  7   13.50%  40  95.20%  2   4.80%   43  95.60%  2   4.40%   68  87.20%  10  12.80%  150 88.80%  19  11.20%  2   100.00%
North Yorkshire 1   50.00%  1   50.00%  92  86.80%  14  13.20%  5   100.00% 0   0.00%   6   75.00%  2   25.00%  6   85.70%  1   14.30%  137 90.70%  14  9.30%   6   85.70%  1   14.30%  19  67.90%  9   32.10%  38  95.00%  2   5.00%   42  87.50%  6   12.50%  11  55.00%  9   45.00%  78  90.70%  8   9.30%   14  100.00%
Nottinghamshire 2   100.00% 0   0.00%   182 71.90%  71  28.10%  12  80.00%  3   20.00%  30  100.00% 0   0.00%   11  57.90%  8   42.10%  241 96.00%  10  4.00%   10  100.00% 0   0.00%   45  86.50%  7   13.50%  100 96.20%  4   3.80%   46  82.10%  10  17.90%  51  78.50%  14  21.50%  154 92.80%  12  7.20%   2   100.00%
South Wales 0   -   0   -   232 72.50%  88  27.50%  13  65.00%  7   35.00%  55  94.80%  3   5.20%   10  100.00% 0   0.00%   289 94.40%  17  5.60%   9   90.00%  1   10.00%  64  97.00%  2   3.00%   112 100.00% 0   0.00%   150 93.20%  11  6.80%   47  87.00%  7   13.00%  323 81.20%  75  18.80%  11  100.00%
South Yorkshire 2   100.00% 0   0.00%   218 80.40%  53  19.60%  18  90.00%  2   10.00%  44  95.70%  2   4.30%   9   64.30%  5   35.70%  350 95.90%  15  4.10%   9   81.80%  2   18.20%  75  91.50%  7   8.50%   114 95.00%  6   5.00%   78  84.80%  14  15.20%  41  85.40%  7   14.60%  162 89.50%  19  10.50%  13  100.00%
Staffordshire   0   -   0   -   150 69.40%  66  30.60%  15  88.20%  2   11.80%  20  95.20%  1   4.80%   8   80.00%  2   20.00%  161 85.60%  27  14.40%  11  91.70%  1   8.30%   55  74.30%  19  25.70%  80  93.00%  6   7.00%   85  81.70%  19  18.30%  63  90.00%  7   10.00%  147 83.10%  30  16.90%  8   100.00%
Suffolk 1   100.00% 0   0.00%   138 87.30%  20  12.70%  7   100.00% 0   0.00%   14  73.70%  5   26.30%  4   80.00%  1   20.00%  111 95.70%  5   4.30%   5   83.30%  1   16.70%  28  90.30%  3   9.70%   40  97.60%  1   2.40%   61  91.00%  6   9.00%   43  86.00%  7   14.00%  68  88.30%  9   11.70%  5   100.00%
Surrey  0   -   0   -   93  75.60%  30  24.40%  11  61.10%  7   38.90%  5   62.50%  3   37.50%  8   88.90%  1   11.10%  111 88.80%  14  11.20%  17  94.40%  1   5.60%   23  82.10%  5   17.90%  55  96.50%  2   3.50%   39  83.00%  8   17.00%  37  71.20%  15  28.80%  134 87.60%  19  12.40%  17  100.00%
Sussex  0   -   0   -   171 80.30%  42  19.70%  15  65.20%  8   34.80%  35  87.50%  5   12.50%  7   100.00% 0   0.00%   190 91.80%  17  8.20%   14  73.70%  5   26.30%  36  85.70%  6   14.30%  80  95.20%  4   4.80%   72  84.70%  13  15.30%  74  72.50%  28  27.50%  161 89.40%  19  10.60%  17  100.00%
Thames Valley   9   100.00% 0   0.00%   214 65.20%  114 34.80%  26  72.20%  10  27.80%  40  87.00%  6   13.00%  10  62.50%  6   37.50%  296 92.50%  24  7.50%   15  83.30%  3   16.70%  51  82.30%  11  17.70%  122 93.10%  9   6.90%   105 84.00%  20  16.00%  32  76.20%  10  23.80%  280 89.70%  32  10.30%  40  100.00%
Warwickshire    0   -   0   -   35  76.10%  11  23.90%  7   87.50%  1   12.50%  10  100.00% 0   0.00%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   76  96.20%  3   3.80%   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   10  83.30%  2   16.70%  18  94.70%  1   5.30%   15  78.90%  4   21.10%  32  91.40%  3   8.60%   154 90.60%  16  9.40%   0   -
West Mercia 1   50.00%  1   50.00%  156 78.80%  42  21.20%  24  85.70%  4   14.30%  14  82.40%  3   17.60%  5   83.30%  1   16.70%  169 93.40%  12  6.60%   5   100.00% 0   0.00%   47  92.20%  4   7.80%   55  98.20%  1   1.80%   66  86.80%  10  13.20%  49  89.10%  6   10.90%  198 88.80%  25  11.20%  3   100.00%
West Midlands   6   66.70%  3   33.30%  413 64.90%  223 35.10%  28  75.70%  9   24.30%  90  82.60%  19  17.40%  55  77.50%  16  22.50%  558 92.20%  47  7.80%   35  97.20%  1   2.80%   109 83.20%  22  16.80%  226 92.60%  18  7.40%   116 77.90%  33  22.10%  164 79.60%  42  20.40%  304 86.10%  49  13.90%  16  100.00%
West Yorkshire  1   100.00% 0   0.00%   420 76.60%  128 23.40%  40  83.30%  8   16.70%  78  80.40%  19  19.60%  30  93.80%  2   6.30%   505 93.70%  34  6.30%   22  88.00%  3   12.00%  86  81.90%  19  18.10%  173 95.60%  8   4.40%   116 80.00%  29  20.00%  52  83.90%  10  16.10%  297 85.10%  52  14.90%  35  100.00%
Wiltshire   1   100.00% 0   0.00%   74  75.50%  24  24.50%  9   69.20%  4   30.80%  6   100.00% 0   0.00%   3   100.00% 0   0.00%   90  92.80%  7   7.20%   4   80.00%  1   20.00%  26  83.90%  5   16.10%  25  100.00% 0   0.00%   22  81.50%  5   18.50%  13  86.70%  2   13.30%  79  85.90%  13  14.10%  10  100.00%
```

I was hoping to get a single file with all the months in one place so I could then perform my Data Analysis on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, your post needs some improvement if you wish to get help. Please read [ask] and write a [mcve]. At this point community will have to guess. Because there is no input sample, no expected output definition.

Comment: What do you mean your merge code "returns nothing"?  There's no "return" statement in the sample code. Have you verified the number of records in each of the parts initially read from disk? in the combined_csv?  after the drop()? written to disk?  Please update with the number of records at each stage and describe which change is the problem.

Comment: @SarahMesser Yes, that is correct,  but it should output to a file ("principal_offence_year_2014.csv") and it doesn't do that. Also the number of records is exactly the same 44 before and 44 after, but due to the way it output I can't see if it actualy makes any changes. When doing single colums it works fine, but the complete code returns the whole file, so I can't actually see the changes.

Comment: Please post a data sample, and also the desired output.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I am basically cleaning up the data set of empty spaces ready to complete scatter plots, and deduce correlation. This process would be a lot easier to do with all the monthly data in one yearly sheet?

Comment: I suggest you add your data sample in raw text format (not an image). It can then be copy/pasted and tested

Comment: What is the last 'output of code'? Is this the *input* csv? Or a copypaste of `combined_csv`? We need a sample of the *input csv* data to be able to debug your code.

Comment: @MartinEvans do you reckon that my code is adaptable to do what you mentioned in (selecting columns for scatter plot from csv) to do what I was trying to do here? because yours is just one line and simplifies the whole solution. I could make it into a function?

Comment: Something like such:
`missing_values = ["--", " ", "0","-"]
dff = pd.read_csv("principal_offence_category_august_2014.csv", na_values = missing_values)
data['principal_offence_category_august_2014.csv'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float')`

Comment: If you read a single one of your files and write it immediately to another file, without any other processing, what is the result? Try with the ".csv" extension and with the full path as part of the file name as well. Also compare the directory where you're looking for the file with the output of os.getcwd().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `.csv` to the end of your output filename.

If you want to combined this with your previous question, you could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

parts = [
    "principal_offence_category_april_2014.csv", 
    "principal_offence_category_august_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_december_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_february_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_january_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_july_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_june_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_march_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_may_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_november_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_october_2014.csv",
    "principal_offence_category_september_2014.csv",
]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(part, thousands=',', na_values=['-', '--']) for part in parts]
df_combined = pd.concat(dfs)
df_combined.columns = [f"V{i}" for i in range(1, len(df_combined.columns)+1)]

for col in df_combined.columns[1:]:
    if df_combined[col].dtype == type(str):
        df_combined[col] = df_combined[col].str.rstrip('%').astype('float')

df_combined.to_csv("principal_offence_year_2014_output.csv", index=False)
```